# What are the '.package-lock.json' files in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I just realized that in the `node_modules` folder, there are several `.package-lock.json` files. What is the use of them? And how are they different from the `package-lock.json` file in the top level folder?

Answer (score 1):

For the package-lock in your node_modules : Those are the informations such as versions, name, author, dependancies,..etc from the respective libraries you installed in your project.

For the package-lock in your root folder : Same informations but directly related to your project.

Comment: My question is about the difference between package-lock.json in top level folder and .package-lock in node_modules